# npm is not working when create laravel mix

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

i'm trying install laravel mix on window and use command line to install. But when use " npm install " which shows error bellow [image: error]

and here is my package.json
[image]
anyone help me solve this! thanks so bad

Comment: Can you copy your errors and your `package.json` instead of the pictures please?

Comment: npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...},"dist":{"shasum":"e'
this is my error

Comment: Looks like there is some error in the lock file, try remove it and install again.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong there.